# Cpp file including while also able to debug in it

Tags: c++, header

In a thread pool implementation:

There is a threadpool.h which has a virtual class threadpool.

```
class ThreadPool {
     funcX (){} = 0
     ...
}
// ThreadPoolImpl not defined or declared in this file.
```

In the corresponding threadpool.cpp, there's the implementation threadpoolImpl which inherits from threadpool.

```
//include threadpool.h header.
class ThreadPoolImpl : public ThreadPool {
      funcX() {....};  // The function I want to debug inside.
}
```

My problems:

In my main function:
If I only include threadpool.h, then 'cause of lack of the threadpoolImpl definition, I get

```
incomplete type not allowed error.
```

If I include threadpool.cpp instead of threadpool.h, I get link error because threadpool.cpp is compiled twice. To solve this, I removed threadpool.cpp from my project. 
However, this way, I can't debug the threadpool.cpp with breakpoints.

Please someone tell  if I can use the threadpoolImpl while also able to debug in it (with VS IDE tools),  or must I rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a threadpoolImpl.h and add the definition of class ThreadPoolImpl to it . And In your main.cpp you only need to include threadpoolImpl.h .

threadpoolImpl.h:

```
#include <threadpool.h>
class ThreadPoolImpl : public ThreadPool {
      funcX();  // The function I want to debug inside.
}
```

threadpoolImpl.cpp:

```
void ThreadPoolImpl::funcX()
{
  //debug here
}
```

It seems like that ThreadPool is a interface in your design.There are some better tools such as design patterns to improve your implements.

Comment: I moved the ThreadPoolImpl to threadPool.h instead of creating a new ThreadPoolImpl.h file. But the threadPoolImpl class can't find its function implementation in threadPool.cpp. Weird. 
Ouch, I've removed the ThreadPool.cpp from project, sorry~

Comment: The code I've been reading should be a unfinished one with codes copied elsewhere (probably from multiple files). I'm grabbing a example to learn pool things..
But I did modify it( moving the threadpoolimpl to its own file.) as you said. Now it's working like I hoped.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You make it sound like you are `#include`ing threadpool.cpp. Don't do that, just make sure it is actually part of the solution/project that it shows up in the Solution Explorer and is being compiled.